# How do I find the keys and the value in a hash with the minimum value, only among certain keys?

Tags: ruby, hash, key, min

Using Ruby 2.4.  I have a hash with keys and values that are both numbers (integers).   Given a set of keys, how do I find the entry (both key and value) that has the lowest value?  If I wanted to find the minimum value I could do

```
my_hash.select{|k, v| my_selected_keys.include?(k) }.values.min_by(&:last)
```

But this only gets me the value, not both the key and the value.  Also note that values in my hash are not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the hash by the value and then take the first element

```
my_hash.select{|k, _| my_selected_keys.include?(k) }.sort_by{|_, v| v}.first
```

Comment: If I saved the result to a varaible, woudl I then access the key and value by running "a.key" and "a.value"?

Comment: No, but the hash class has a `[]` for turning an array into a hash, so you could do this: `Hash[*my_hash.select{|k, _| my_selected_keys.include?(k) }.sort_by{|_, v| v}.first]` (note that you have to add the splat (`*`) operator before `my_hash` for this to work).

Answer (score 1):

You can map the selected keys `sel_keys`:

```
hash = {1 => 2, 3 => 1, 4 => 5, 5 => 1} 
sel_keys = [3, 4] 
sel_keys.map { |k| [k,hash[k]] }.min_by(&:last) #=> [3, 1]
```

Caveat: This returns only the first key found with the min value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

It gets all keys that have the minimum value. I've split out and named many of the intermediate objects for clarity:

```
hash = { 4 => 5, 2 => 9, 3 => 1, 8 => 5 }
selected = Set[2, 4, 8]

hash_subset = hash.slice(*selected)
keys_by_value = hash_subset.group_by(&:last).each_value { |group| group.map!(&:first) }

min_value, keys_with_min_val = keys_by_value.min_by(&:first)
# => [5, [4, 8]]
```

and the obligatory ruby oneliner:

`hash.slice(*selected).group_by(&:pop).each_value(&:flatten!).min_by(&:first)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution

```
hash.reduce([nil, Float::INFINITY]) { |acc, pair| acc[1] < pair[1] ? acc : pair }
```